# Why I cannot reach the svg objects using from html object?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

Example on the Internet, they can call objects in svg files easily. But i cannot reach them. Here is my html code``

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>SVG Example</title>
    <script src="mysvg.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button style="width: 100px; height: 50px" onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
        <object data="test.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my .js file code:

```
function changeColor() {
  const svg = document.getElementById("layer1");
  const motor1 = document.getElementById("g320");
  const ellipse = document.getElementById("ellipse205");
  ellipse.setAttribute("style","fill:green;stroke:green;stroke-width:2");
  motor1.appendChild(svg);
  ellipse.appendChild(motor1);
}
```

What i do wrong, why this is not working? I do not understand.

Comment: Because with ``<object>`` you load it similar to an ``<img>`` tag; the SVG does **not** become part of the main DOM, thus you can't access it. If you can't inline the SVG, you [have to load it](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman This is plain wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The content of a SVG `<object>` is part of a different DOM than the host document. Accessing it is a two-step process:

- wait for the content to load
- access its DOM with [`HTMLObjectElement.contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/contentDocument)

Like this:

```
document.querySelector('object[data="test.svg"]').addEventListener("load", function () {
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", changeColor);
}

function changeColor() {
    const innerDocument = this.contentDocument;
    const svg = innerDocument.getElementById("layer1");
    const motor1 = innerDocument.getElementById("g320");
    const ellipse = innerDocument.getElementById("ellipse205");
    ellipse.setAttribute("style","fill:green;stroke:green;stroke-width:2");
    motor1.appendChild(svg);
    ellipse.appendChild(motor1);
}
```

Note that this sort of access is subject to the [Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). It means that the host HTML file and the SVG either need to be served from the same domain, or from `localhost`, or a [CORS header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) must explicitely allow it. If you load them with the `file://` protocol, `this.contentDocument` will also return `null`.

Comment: So when I say not the same DOM, I  am wrong, . And when you say different DOM you are right...

Comment: Maybe you should add to your answer that this should run from a web server and not directly from the file system.